# Display inline with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I have some cards who are supposed to be inline, but I have to use a display none on them. When I click on a specific button, I want to display these cards; but when I do that, each cards appears to take a row when I want to have them on the same row

```
    <div class="row" id="menu_lv2r">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="card card-chart">
                <div class="card-header">Character 1</div>
                <div class="card-body card-body-top">
                    <img class="card-img" alt="character_image" src="./images/char1.jpg"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="card card-chart">
                <div class="card-header">Character 2</div>
                <div class="card-body card-body-top">
                    <img class="card-img" alt="character_image" src="./images/char2.jpg"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Theses were my 2 cards examples

If I let the code like that, they are all inline which is what I want

Now If I add some css to hide them

```
#menu_lv2r{
    display: none;
}
```

The row with the 2 cards disapeared which is still fine.

But now, when I use some Js to print them again, they appear in one row each.

```
var elt = document.getElementById('menu_lv2r');
elt.style.display = "inline";
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use display: flex for parent element.

```
elt.style.display = "flex";
```

It's the default value for bootstrap class .row.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thanks ! I will try to remember it.

Comment: @Minirock I'd recommend you to use bootstrap utilities for hiding and showing though. They have good docs, check'em out. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/

Answer (score 0):

Just use flex instead of inline. Everything works fine